# Convert String to List of Numbers

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to create a function that when a string is entered it will turn it into a list of numbers, these numbers are the numerical form of the characters in the string.

e.g. `a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4` and `space = 27` (other punctuation may be needed).

So if I had the string `"hello"`, my result would be: `{8, 5, 12, 12, 15}`

I had a look at `StringReplace`, `StringSplit` and `Characters`, but not sure what is optimal.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start by using [`ToCharacterCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToCharacterCode.html) then applying whatever rules you want using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html).

For example, to get "a" aligned to one we will need to subtract 96 from the ASCII value:

```
string = "hello world";
rules = {-64 -> 27};
ToCharacterCode[string] - 96
% /. rules
```

> ```
> {8, 5, 12, 12, 15, -64, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4}
>
> {8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 27, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4}
> ```

---

Less efficiently but also perhaps easier to work with for mapping a few characters atypically (such as space above) you can do this:

```
Characters @ string /.
  {" " -> 27, x_String :> ToCharacterCode[x] - 96} // Flatten
```

{8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 27, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4}

The rules have priority by order therefore `ToCharacterCode` is only used on the characters you haven't already replaced.

---

It may help to have a sense of the ASCII mapping:

```
FromCharacterCode[Range[32, 126]]
```

> ```
> " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
> ```

Comment: Wow, so many hidden features in Mathematica, This is brilliant

Comment: @user9053 Yes, even people who have been using it for years continue to find new things.